# Azure AD Graph API $filter not working with spaces

Tags: .net, azure, azure-ad-graph-api

I want to filter groups based on `displayName`.

This works:

```
https://graph.windows.net/x.onmicrosoft.com/groups?$filter=displayName%20eq%20'Programmers'"&api-version=2013-11-08
```

This doesn't:

```
https://graph.windows.net/x.onmicrosoft.com/groups?$filter=displayName%20eq%20'Web%20Developers'api-version=2013-11-08
```

Note the space in `Web%20Developers`. Groups without a space work, groups with a space do not.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> https://graph.windows.net/x.onmicrosoft.com/groups?$filter=displayName%20eq%20'Web%20Developers'api-version=2013-11-08

Please check your request url carefully. I think there is something wrong with it. We need to **add '&'** in the part `'Web%20Developers'api-version=2013-11-08`

I have tested on my local with api-version 1.6. The space in group name does not affect our result. See more detailed information with following screenshot:
[image]